# Не обновляется страница на Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

Решил попытаться изучить Angular и с самого начала уперся в стену.
Делал попытки на angular 6 и 4. Проблема выглядит одинаково.

Первая страница, появляющаяся сразу после установки, не обновляется, ни после сохранения измененных файлов html или css, ни даже после обновления страницы браузера клавишей F5. Чтобы информация обновилась,нужно вырубить и заново запустить сервер при помощи ng serve и только после этого страница изменяется. Более того ng test при запуске начинает показывать ошибки, если содержимое файлов не соответствует предустановленному.

Я безыдеен

Comment: А в консоле нет ошибок?

Comment: Неа, в консоли ничего кроме "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в package.json, если у вас webpack, добавить параметр `--poll=1000`

```
"server": "ng serve --port 4210 --host 0.0.0.0 --poll=1000 --sourcemap=false --aot",
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это сработало!

Comment: Рад помочь)))))